# javascript multidimensional array problems

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I've been having problems creating an multidimensional array in javascript
I have 2 arrays generated with PHP from a db.
I want to create an array with the ID from ug_v_id & assign keys with mixed values

The error occurs when I get to 'ug_arr[ug_v_id]['id'] = ug_v_id;' it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined"

```
var ug_view_arr = [1, 2]; //from db
var ug_list_arr = {"1":{"id":"1","company_id":"1","title":"test","type":"staff"}}; //from db
var ug_arr = new Array();

if(ug_view_arr_len>0){
    for (i=0; i<ug_view_arr_len; i++) {
        ug_v_id = ug_view_arr[i];
        ug_arr[i] = new Array(ug_view_arr_len);
        ug_arr[ug_v_id]['id'] = ug_v_id;
        ug_arr[ug_v_id]['name'] = ug_list_arr[ug_v_id]['title'];
        ug_arr[ug_v_id]['uType'] = ug_list_arr[ug_v_id]['type'];
        ug_arr[ug_v_id]['pType'] = 'Usergroup';
        ug_arr[ug_v_id]['view'] = true;
        ug_arr[ug_v_id]['edit'] = false;    
    }
}
```

Any help would much be appreciated

Comment: where you set `ug_view_arr_len` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var ug_view_arr = [1, 2]; //from db
var ug_list_arr = {"1":{"id":"1","company_id":"1","title":"test1","type":"staff1"}, "2":{"id":"2","company_id":"2","title":"test2","type":"staff2"}}; //from db
var ug_arr = [];

if(ug_view_arr.length>0){
    for (i=0; i<ug_view_arr.length; i++) {
        ug_v_id = ug_view_arr[i];   
        ug_arr[ug_v_id] = {
        id:    ug_v_id,
            name:  ug_list_arr[ug_v_id]['title'],
            uType: ug_list_arr[ug_v_id]['type'],
            pType: 'Usergroup',
            view:  true,
            edit:  false
        };    
    }
}
```